# How to disable gutter "override" icons in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, configuration, icons, gutter

There seems to be no way I can disable IntelliJ's "override" icons, which look like:

[image: gutter icon]

When I hover over the little icon, this text is displayed as a tool tip:

> Implements method 'accept' in java.util.function.Consumer
> *Click or press Ctrl+U to navigate*

To reproduce, use this class:

```java
class Foo implements Consumer<T> {

    @Override
    public void accept(T t) {
    }
}
```

They are very annoying, of absolutely no use to me whatsoever (isn't that what the `@Override` annotation is for?), and all but prevent me setting breakpoints using my mouse (although I can do it using fine motor skills).

I have turned off all options in *Settings > General > Gutter Icons*, which interestingly/significantly does *not* include an "implements" option, but the above annoyance persists.

How can I turn them off?

I'm using the latest IntelliJ - version 2016.1

Comment: They annoy me because the width of the line number area starts bouncing around as it tries to parse the garbage code I'm working on.

Answer (score 10):

Those are called *Gutter Icons* and you can disable each in "Settings, Editor, General, Gutter Icons".

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it  doesn't work. I un-ticked everything in the gutter settings, but I still get the little icon as per my question, which is to mark a method that implements an interface like in my question. I have updated the question to be more specific

Comment: This works perfectly for me, that preferences area even includes a specific check box for this particular icon ("Implementing method").

Comment: It doesn't help at all. Icons unchecked but still I see them. The only solution - hide all Gutter icons.